# How to sort values with VBA without changing the formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

The code does exactly what it should, but i would like to know if there is away to sort the values only, without changing the formatting?
As of now the cells in the ranges have 2 different colors. So is it possible to prevent it from messing up the color scheme?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Range("A36:H160").UnMerge

    Range("A36:H160").Sort Key1:=Range("B36")

    Order1 = xlAscending
    Header = xlNo

    Range("E36:H160").Merge (True)


    Range("K36:R76").UnMerge

    Range("K36:R76").Sort Key1:=Range("L36")

    Order1 = xlAscending
    Header = xlNo

    Range("O36:R76").Merge (True)

End Sub
```

[image: Workbook]

Comment: Try conditional formatting maybe?

Comment: The formatting isn't based on any conditions. It is more of a design theme. When it changes around on the dates, it changes this pattern of colors.

Comment: Copy your range to empty range, sort in new range, copy value to original range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to save the colors and restore them after the Sort.

Also, your Sort code is not quite right.

And since you are repeating the process, I'd seperate the sort/color code into a Private Sub

Something like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    DotheSort Range("A36:H160"), Range("B36"), Range("E36:H160")
    DotheSort Range("K36:R76"), Range("L36"), Range("O36:R76")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Private Sub DotheSort(rSrc As Range, rSortOn As Range, rMerge As Range)
    Dim colors As Variant
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long

    ' save colors
    ReDim colors(1 To rSrc.Rows.Count, 1 To rSrc.Columns.Count)
    For cl = 1 To UBound(colors, 2)
        For rw = 1 To UBound(colors, 1)
            colors(rw, cl) = rSrc.Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color
        Next
    Next

    rSrc.UnMerge
    rSrc.Sort Key1:=rSortOn, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    rMerge.Merge True

    'Restore colors
    For cl = 1 To UBound(colors, 2)
        For rw = 1 To UBound(colors, 1)
            rSrc.Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color = colors(rw, cl)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This brought a tear to my eye not only because it is beautiful and works flawlessly but it made me feel inadequate at the same time! Thanks a bunch! Where can i learn this??

Comment: Thanks @Strune.  _Where can i learn this?_ I'd say right here on SO!.  Pick a few of the top [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel/topusers)/[VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/topusers) users and browse there answers.  There is quite a bit of [wheat scattered in amongst a lot of chaff](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/separate+the+wheat+from+the+chaff).

Comment: Hoped you'd say that, because people always say google is the answer but i have searched far and wide only to find this code, that to be honest, froze the program for sec. lol Thank you so much!

Comment: What if you don't just want to overlay a pre-set colour scheme but actually want the macro to register the format of each cell pre-sort and then re-apply it post sort? I have some cells that have strikethrough font but finding it super difficult to find a way to make Excel 'memorise' which ones are before sorting them..!!